# How to separate a given type of file from others?

Tags: command-line

I have a folder containing about 6000 .pdf, .jpg, .doc and .djvu files out of which I want to separate all the .djvu files and move them to another new folder. I was wondering if there is a quicker way to do so than handpicking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
mv *.djvu target_directory/
```